# changing placeholder of an input via <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onchange

I need some help with changing the placeholder of an input via `<select>`,

I mean I need to change the placeholder of an input if the option of the `<select>` has been changed

My code:

```
<select id="select" name="se">
   <!-- if this is chosen placeholder will be 'you have chosen option n1' !-->
   <option value="1">option 1</option>
   <!-- if this is chosen placeholder will be 'you have chosen option n2' !-->
   <option value="2">option 2</option>
   <!-- if this is chosen placeholder will be 'you have chosen option n3' !-->
   <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="choosen">
```

Comment: do you mean to display the desired text in the textbox ?

Comment: @DinoMyte yeah thats what im talking about

Comment: that is `value` not `placeholder`. Placeholder is the hint you see when there is no value

Comment: It looks like you haven't attempted to solve your own problem. [Please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('select').on("change",function()
{
   $('#inp').val("you have chosen option n" + $.trim(this.value));
}).change();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/zcL12b1u/1/